# How to convert date to a different format in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, int, varchar

I do have this sample value of `"12/01/2013"` which is a string.

How can I convert it directly to an SQL statement? The format must be in `INT`, like this: `20131201`

So from `"12/01/2013"` to `20131201`.

Answer (score 1):

See [Data Type Formatting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
select cast(to_char(to_timestamp('12/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYYMMDD') as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

this works with **SQL Server**

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING('12/01/2013',7,4) + 
                    SUBSTRING('12/01/2013',0,3) + 
                    SUBSTRING('12/01/2013',4,2)) AS dateInt
```

Result

```
20131201
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in MySQL:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR("12/01/2013",7,4), SUBSTR("12/01/2013",4,2),SUBSTR("12/01/2013",1,2)) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 0):

In postgreSQL you have the `to_date` function which accepts a date string and a format string and returns a date.

So you can:

```
postgres=# select to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
  to_date   
------------
 2015-12-01
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_date('12012015', 'mmddyyyy');
  to_date   
------------
 2015-12-01
(1 row)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using CONVERT and REPLACE  function like below.

```
DECLARE @dateValue date
SET @dateValue =  CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/01/2013',102)
SELECT REPLACE ( CONVERT(nvarchar,@dateValue) , '-' , '' )
```

Rsult will be

```
20131201
```